# Is there a built in function for string natural sort?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of strings for which I would like to perform a [natural alphabetical sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order).

For instance, the following list is naturally sorted (what I want):

```
['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13']
```

And here's the "sorted" version of the above list (what I get using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted)):

```
['Elm11', 'Elm12', 'Elm2', 'elm0', 'elm1', 'elm10', 'elm13', 'elm9']
```

I'm looking for a sort function which behaves like the first one.

Comment: related: [Python analog of natsort function (sort a list using a "natural order" algorithm)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545532/python-analog-of-natsort-function-sort-a-list-using-a-natural-order-algorithm)

Answer (score 373, accepted):

There is a third party library for this on PyPI called [natsort](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) (full disclosure, I am the package's author).  For your case, you can do either of the following:

```
>>> from natsort import natsorted, ns
>>> x = ['Elm11', 'Elm12', 'Elm2', 'elm0', 'elm1', 'elm10', 'elm13', 'elm9']
>>> natsorted(x, key=lambda y: y.lower())
['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13']
>>> natsorted(x, alg=ns.IGNORECASE)  # or alg=ns.IC
['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13']
```

You should note that `natsort` uses a general algorithm so it should work for just about any input that you throw at it. If you want more details on why you might choose a library to do this rather than rolling your own function, check out the `natsort` documentation's [How It Works](http://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howitworks.html) page, in particular the [Special Cases Everywhere!](http://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howitworks.html#special-cases-everywhere) section.

---

If you need a sorting key instead of a sorting function, use either of the below formulas.

```
>>> from natsort import natsort_keygen, ns
>>> l1 = ['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13']
>>> l2 = l1[:]
>>> natsort_key1 = natsort_keygen(key=lambda y: y.lower())
>>> l1.sort(key=natsort_key1)
>>> l1
['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13']
>>> natsort_key2 = natsort_keygen(alg=ns.IGNORECASE)
>>> l2.sort(key=natsort_key2)
>>> l2
['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13']
```

---

**Update November 2020**

Given that a popular request/question is "how to sort like Windows Explorer?" (or whatever is your operating system's file system browser), as of `natsort` version 7.1.0 there is a function called [`os_sorted`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#natsort.os_sorted) to do exactly this. On Windows, it will sort in the same order as Windows Explorer, and on other operating systems it should sort like whatever is the local file system browser.

```py
>>> from natsort import os_sorted
>>> os_sorted(list_of_paths)
# your paths sorted like your file system browser
```

For those needing a sort key, you can use `os_sort_keygen` (or `os_sort_key` if you just need the defaults).

*Caveat* - Please read the API documentation for this function before you use to understand the limitations and how to get best results.

Comment: I also think it's quite interesting that natsort also sorts correct when the number is not at the end: like it's often the case for filenames. Feel free to include the following example:  http://pastebin.com/9cwCLdEK

Comment: Natsort is a great library, should be added to python standard library! :-)

Comment: `natsort` also 'naturally' handles the case of multiple separate numbers in the strings. Great stuff!

Comment: @SethMMorton Windows sorts files in this order `['!2020', '.2020', '2020']`. Natsort returns `['2020', '!2020', '.2020']`. Can it sort like Windows?

Comment: Thank you for `os_sorted`, that's worked for me to match the ordering in Finder on my Mac.

Comment: Is there a way to access other OSes sort orders? For instance, if I'm on unix but I want to sort like Windows Explorer?

Comment: @Stef No not really. See https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort/issues/150 for the gory details.

Answer (score 263):

Try this:

```
import re

def natural_sort(l): 
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key)]
    return sorted(l, key=alphanum_key)
```

Output:

```
['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13']
```

Code adapted from here: [Sorting for Humans : Natural Sort Order](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html).

Comment: why do you use `return sorted(l, key)` instead of `l.sort(key)`? Is it for any performance gain or just to be more pythonic?

Comment: @jperelli I think the ladder would change the original list in the caller. But most likely the caller wants another shallow copy of the list.

Comment: Just for the record, this can't handle all inputs: the str/int splits must line up, otherwise you'll create comparisons like ["foo",0] < [0,"foo"] for the input ["foo0","0foo"], which raises a TypeError.

Comment: @user19087: In fact it does work, because `re.split('([0-9]+)', '0foo')` returns `['', '0', 'foo']`. Because of that, strings will always be on even indexes and integers on odd indexes in the array.

Comment: For anyone wondering about performance, this is notably slower than python's native sort. i.e. 25 -50x slower. And if you want to always sort [elm1, elm2, Elm2, elm2] as [elm1, Elm2, elm2, elm2] reliably (caps before lower), then you can simply call natural_sort(sorted(lst)). More inefficient, but very easy to get a repeatable sort.  Compile the regex for a ~50% speedup. as seen in Claudiu's answer.

Comment: `isdigit` is probably not what you want: `'\u00B23455'.isdigit()` evaluates to true, but `int('²3455')` will fail. (Same to @Claudiu)

Comment: @Caesar: Sounds like a bug because the docs for `str.isdigit()` say "Return `True` if all bytes in the sequence are **ASCII** decimal digits..." (bold mine). Regardless, maybe `'\u00B23455'.isdecimal()` would be a better choice.

Comment: @martineau Uhm? Which version of the docs are you looking at? "Digits include decimal characters and digits that need special handling, such as the compatibility superscript digits. This covers digits which cannot be used to form numbers in base 10, like the Kharosthi numbers. " https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html (Similar for python 2, even…)

Comment: split gives empty strings, I use `findall()` with `/(\d+|\D+)/` see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69697978/810282

Comment: Whenever I try to use this solution, the line `alphanum_key = lambda key: ...` throws the error `File "/usr/lib/python3.10/re.py", line 230, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`.  Did something change about how `re.split()` works since this answer was written?

Answer (score 145):

Here's a much more pythonic version of Mark Byer's answer:

```
import re

def natural_sort_key(s, _nsre=re.compile('([0-9]+)')):
    return [int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
            for text in _nsre.split(s)]
```

Now this function can be used as a key in any function that uses it, like `list.sort`, `sorted`, `max`, etc.

As a lambda:

```
lambda s: [int(t) if t.isdigit() else t.lower() for t in re.split('(\d+)', s)]
```

---

Fully reproducible demo code:

```
import re
natsort = lambda s: [int(t) if t.isdigit() else t.lower() for t in re.split('(\d+)', s)]
L = ["a1", "a10", "a11", "a2", "a22", "a3"]   
print(sorted(L, key=natsort))  
# ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a10', 'a11', 'a22']
```

Comment: re module compiles and caches regexes automagically, so there is no need to precompile

Comment: @wim: it caches the last X usages, so it's technically possible to use X+5 regexes and then do a natural sort over and over, at which point this wouldn't be cached. but probably negligible in the long run

Comment: I did not do it, but perhaps the reason was that it can't handle tuples, like a regular python sort.

Comment: The X usages mentioned by @Claudiu seem to be **100** on Python 2.7 and **512** on Python 3.4. And also note that when the limit is reached the cache is completely cleared (so it's not only the oldest one that is thrown out).

Comment: @Zitrax Why / How does it make sense to clear the cache completely?

Comment: @Joschua I just mentioned what python is doing internally - perhaps it might just be the simplest solution. You can read more about this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17325281/11722

Comment: For anyone wondering about performance, this version of natural sort is about 10-15x slower than python's native sort.

Comment: This doesn't work when the list elements are `Path` objects. You can modify your function to make it work though, just replace the last `_nsre.split(s)` with `_nsre.split(str(s))`. Same for the lambda, replace `s` with `str(s)` at the end of the expression.

Comment: Why did you use `[0-9]` in the function and `\d` in the lambda? As far as I know those are equal, but wouldnt it make sense to adjust the answer then to use only one of the two?

Comment: Blame @Zitrax :D ( https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16090640/7 )

Answer (score 25):

```
data = ['elm13', 'elm9', 'elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm11', 'Elm2', 'elm10']
```

Let's analyse the data. The digit capacity of all elements is 2. And there are 3 letters in common literal part `'elm'`.

So, the maximal length of element is 5. We can increase this value to make sure (for example, to 8).

**Bearing that in mind, we've got a one-line solution:**

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: '{0:0>8}'.format(x).lower())
```

**without regular expressions and external libraries!**

```
print(data)

>>> ['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'elm13']
```

Explanation:

```
for elm in data:
    print('{0:0>8}'.format(elm).lower())

>>>
0000elm0
0000elm1
0000elm2
0000elm9
000elm10
000elm11
000elm13
```

Comment: This doesn't handle dynamic/unknown length data. It also sorts differently than other solutions for data that has numbers within the data opposed to at the end. *This isn't necessarily undesirable but I think it's good to point out.

Comment: If you need to handle dynamic length data you can use `width = max(data, key=len)` to calculate what to sub in for the `8` above and then sub it into the format string with `'{0:0>{width}}'.format(x, width=width)`

Comment: Just by doing a timed test compared to all the others on this forum, this solution is by far the **fastest** and most efficient for the type of data @snakile is trying to process

Comment: FYI the built-in function `str.zfill(width)` returns a copy of the string left filled with ASCII `0` digits to make a string of length _width_. See official documentation to learn more: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill

Answer (score 21):

I wrote a function based on http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html which adds the ability to still pass in your own 'key' parameter. I need this in order to perform a natural sort of lists that contain more complex objects (not just strings).

```
import re

def natural_sort(list, key=lambda s:s):
    """
    Sort the list into natural alphanumeric order.
    """
    def get_alphanum_key_func(key):
        convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text 
        return lambda s: [convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key(s))]
    sort_key = get_alphanum_key_func(key)
    list.sort(key=sort_key)
```

For example:

```
my_list = [{'name':'b'}, {'name':'10'}, {'name':'a'}, {'name':'1'}, {'name':'9'}]
natural_sort(my_list, key=lambda x: x['name'])
print my_list
[{'name': '1'}, {'name': '9'}, {'name': '10'}, {'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'}]
```

Comment: a simpler way to do this would be to define `natural_sort_key`, and then when sorting a list you could do chain your keys, e.g.: `list.sort(key=lambda el: natural_sort_key(el['name']))`

Comment: You can also return `list.sort(key=sort_key)` if you want to, er, return it (e.g. in a lambda). Also you shouldn't really name a var after the built-in `list`. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Given:

```
data = ['Elm11', 'Elm12', 'Elm2', 'elm0', 'elm1', 'elm10', 'elm13', 'elm9']
```

Similar to SergO's solution, a **1-liner without external libraries would be**:

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[3:]))
```

or

```
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x[3:]))
```

Explanation:

This solution uses the *key* feature of *sort* to define a function that will be employed for the sorting. Because we know that every data entry is preceded by 'elm' the sorting function converts to integer the portion of the string after the 3rd character (i.e. int(x[3:])). If the numerical part of the data is in a different location, then this part of the function would have to change.

Comment: I dont think that relying on the 3 character long prefix is a good idea. This is very inflexible in the long run.

Answer (score 9):

**And now for something more* elegant (pythonic)** *-just a touch*

There are many implementations out there, and while some have come close, none quite captured the elegance modern python affords.

- Tested using python(3.5.1)
- Included an additional list to demonstrate that it works when the
  numbers are mid string
- Didn't test, however, I am assuming that if your list was sizable it would be more efficient to compile the regex beforehand

  - *I'm sure someone will correct me if this is an erroneous assumption*

**Quicky**

```python
from re import compile, split    
dre = compile(r'(\d+)')
mylist.sort(key=lambda l: [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s.lower() for s in split(dre, l)])
```

**Full-Code**

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding=utf-8
"""
Natural-Sort Test
"""

from re import compile, split

dre = compile(r'(\d+)')
mylist = ['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13', 'elm']
mylist2 = ['e0lm', 'e1lm', 'E2lm', 'e9lm', 'e10lm', 'E12lm', 'e13lm', 'elm', 'e01lm']

mylist.sort(key=lambda l: [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s.lower() for s in split(dre, l)])
mylist2.sort(key=lambda l: [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s.lower() for s in split(dre, l)])

print(mylist)  
  # ['elm', 'elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13']
print(mylist2)  
  # ['e0lm', 'e1lm', 'e01lm', 'E2lm', 'e9lm', 'e10lm', 'E12lm', 'e13lm', 'elm']
```

**Caution** when using

- `from os.path import split`

  - you will need to differentiate the imports

**Inspiration** from

- [Python Documentation- Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/sorting.html)
- [Sorting for Humans : Natural Sort Order](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/)
- [Human Sorting](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712.html#e20071211T054956)
- Contributors/Commentators to this and referenced posts

Answer (score 7):

## Value Of This Post

My point is to offer a non regex solution that can be applied generally.
I'll create three functions:

1. `find_first_digit` which I borrowed from [@AnuragUniyal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4510805/2336654).  It will find the position of the first digit or non-digit in a string.
2. `split_digits` which is a generator that picks apart a string into digit and non digit chunks.  It will also `yield` integers when it is a digit.
3. `natural_key` just wraps `split_digits` into a `tuple`.  This is what we use as a key for `sorted`, `max`, `min`.

## Functions

```
def find_first_digit(s, non=False):
    for i, x in enumerate(s):
        if x.isdigit() ^ non:
            return i
    return -1

def split_digits(s, case=False):
    non = True
    while s:
        i = find_first_digit(s, non)
        if i == 0:
            non = not non
        elif i == -1:
            yield int(s) if s.isdigit() else s if case else s.lower()
            s = ''
        else:
            x, s = s[:i], s[i:]
            yield int(x) if x.isdigit() else x if case else x.lower()

def natural_key(s, *args, **kwargs):
    return tuple(split_digits(s, *args, **kwargs))
```

We can see that it is general in that we can have multiple digit chunks:

```
# Note that the key has lower case letters
natural_key('asl;dkfDFKJ:sdlkfjdf809lkasdjfa_543_hh')

('asl;dkfdfkj:sdlkfjdf', 809, 'lkasdjfa_', 543, '_hh')
```

Or leave as case sensitive:

```
natural_key('asl;dkfDFKJ:sdlkfjdf809lkasdjfa_543_hh', True)

('asl;dkfDFKJ:sdlkfjdf', 809, 'lkasdjfa_', 543, '_hh')
```

---

We can see that it sorts the OP's list in the appropriate order

```
sorted(
    ['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13'],
    key=natural_key
)

['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13']
```

But it can handle more complicated lists as well:

```
sorted(
    ['f_1', 'e_1', 'a_2', 'g_0', 'd_0_12:2', 'd_0_1_:2'],
    key=natural_key
)

['a_2', 'd_0_1_:2', 'd_0_12:2', 'e_1', 'f_1', 'g_0']
```

---

My regex equivalent would be

```
def int_maybe(x):
    return int(x) if str(x).isdigit() else x

def split_digits_re(s, case=False):
    parts = re.findall('\d+|\D+', s)
    if not case:
        return map(int_maybe, (x.lower() for x in parts))
    else:
        return map(int_maybe, parts)
    
def natural_key_re(s, *args, **kwargs):
    return tuple(split_digits_re(s, *args, **kwargs))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I want to add however, that if you have "12345_A" and "12345_A2", the latter will be sorted before the first. This is at least not how Windows does it. Still works for the above problem, though!

Answer (score 5):

An improvement on Claudiu's improvement on Mark Byers' answer ;-)

```python
import re

def natural_sort_key(s, _re=re.compile(r'(\d+)')):
    return [int(t) if i & 1 else t.lower() for i, t in enumerate(_re.split(s))]

...
my_naturally_sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=natural_sort_key)
```

BTW, maybe not everyone remembers that function argument defaults are evaluated at `def` time

Answer (score 4):

One option is to turn the string into a tuple and replace digits using expanded form http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_expanded_form_mean

that way a90 would become ("a",90,0) and a1 would become ("a",1)

below is some sample code (which isn't very efficient due to the way It removes leading 0's from numbers)

```
alist=["something1",
    "something12",
    "something17",
    "something2",
    "something25and_then_33",
    "something25and_then_34",
    "something29",
    "beta1.1",
    "beta2.3.0",
    "beta2.33.1",
    "a001",
    "a2",
    "z002",
    "z1"]

def key(k):
    nums=set(list("0123456789"))
        chars=set(list(k))
    chars=chars-nums
    for i in range(len(k)):
        for c in chars:
            k=k.replace(c+"0",c)
    l=list(k)
    base=10
    j=0
    for i in range(len(l)-1,-1,-1):
        try:
            l[i]=int(l[i])*base**j
            j+=1
        except:
            j=0
    l=tuple(l)
    print l
    return l

print sorted(alist,key=key)
```

output:

```
('s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', 1)
('s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', 10, 2)
('s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', 10, 7)
('s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', 2)
('s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', 20, 5, 'a', 'n', 'd', '_', 't', 'h', 'e', 'n', '_', 30, 3)
('s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', 20, 5, 'a', 'n', 'd', '_', 't', 'h', 'e', 'n', '_', 30, 4)
('s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', 20, 9)
('b', 'e', 't', 'a', 1, '.', 1)
('b', 'e', 't', 'a', 2, '.', 3, '.')
('b', 'e', 't', 'a', 2, '.', 30, 3, '.', 1)
('a', 1)
('a', 2)
('z', 2)
('z', 1)
['a001', 'a2', 'beta1.1', 'beta2.3.0', 'beta2.33.1', 'something1', 'something2', 'something12', 'something17', 'something25and_then_33', 'something25and_then_34', 'something29', 'z1', 'z002']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution only works for Python 2.X.  For Python 3, `('b', 1) < ('b', 'e', 't', 'a', 1, '.', 1)` will return `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()`

Comment: @SethMMorgon is right, this code easily breaks in Python 3. The natural alternative would seem `natsort`, https://pypi.org/project/natsort/

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answers here, I wrote a `natural_sorted` function that behaves like the built-in function `sorted`:

```
# Copyright (C) 2018, Benjamin Drung <bdrung@posteo.de>
#
# Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
# purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
# copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES
# WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
# MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR
# ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES
# WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN
# ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF
# OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.

import re

def natural_sorted(iterable, key=None, reverse=False):
    """Return a new naturally sorted list from the items in *iterable*.

    The returned list is in natural sort order. The string is ordered
    lexicographically (using the Unicode code point number to order individual
    characters), except that multi-digit numbers are ordered as a single
    character.

    Has two optional arguments which must be specified as keyword arguments.

    *key* specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
    comparison key from each list element: ``key=str.lower``.  The default value
    is ``None`` (compare the elements directly).

    *reverse* is a boolean value.  If set to ``True``, then the list elements are
    sorted as if each comparison were reversed.

    The :func:`natural_sorted` function is guaranteed to be stable. A sort is
    stable if it guarantees not to change the relative order of elements that
    compare equal --- this is helpful for sorting in multiple passes (for
    example, sort by department, then by salary grade).
    """
    prog = re.compile(r"(\d+)")

    def alphanum_key(element):
        """Split given key in list of strings and digits"""
        return [int(c) if c.isdigit() else c for c in prog.split(key(element)
                if key else element)]

    return sorted(iterable, key=alphanum_key, reverse=reverse)
```

The source code is also available in my GitHub snippets repository:
https://github.com/bdrung/snippets/blob/master/natural_sorted.py

Answer (score 3):

Most likely `functools.cmp_to_key()` is closely tied to the underlying implementation of python's sort. Besides, the *cmp* parameter is legacy. The modern way is to transform the input items into objects that support the desired rich comparison operations.

Under CPython 2.x, objects of disparate types can be ordered even if the respective rich comparison operators haven't been implemented. Under CPython 3.x, objects of different types must explicitly support the comparison. See [How does Python compare string and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270689) which links to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons). Most of the answers depend on this implicit ordering. Switching to Python 3.x will require a new type to implement and unify comparisons between numbers and strings.

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Sep 29 2016, 13:30:34) 
>>> (0,"foo") < ("foo",0)
True
```

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct 14 2016, 12:54:53) 
>>> (0,"foo") < ("foo",0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
```

There are three different approaches. The first uses nested classes to take advantage of Python's `Iterable` comparison algorithm. The second unrolls this nesting into a single class. The third foregoes subclassing `str` to focus on performance. All are timed; the second is twice as fast while the third almost six times faster. Subclassing `str` isn't required, and was probably a bad idea in the first place, but it does come with certain conveniences.

The sort characters are duplicated to force ordering by case, and case-swapped to force lower case letter to sort first; this is the typical definition of "natural sort". I couldn't decide on the type of grouping; some might prefer the following, which also brings significant performance benefits:

```
d = lambda s: s.lower()+s.swapcase()
```

Where utilized, the comparison operators are set to that of `object` so they won't [be ignored by `functools.total_ordering`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/functools.py#l192).

```
import functools
import itertools


@functools.total_ordering
class NaturalStringA(str):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}({})".format\
            ( type(self).__name__
            , super().__repr__()
            )
    d = lambda c, s: [ c.NaturalStringPart("".join(v))
                        for k,v in
                       itertools.groupby(s, c.isdigit)
                     ]
    d = classmethod(d)
    @functools.total_ordering
    class NaturalStringPart(str):
        d = lambda s: "".join(c.lower()+c.swapcase() for c in s)
        d = staticmethod(d)
        def __lt__(self, other):
            if not isinstance(self, type(other)):
                return NotImplemented
            try:
                return int(self) < int(other)
            except ValueError:
                if self.isdigit():
                    return True
                elif other.isdigit():
                    return False
                else:
                    return self.d(self) < self.d(other)
        def __eq__(self, other):
            if not isinstance(self, type(other)):
                return NotImplemented
            try:
                return int(self) == int(other)
            except ValueError:
                if self.isdigit() or other.isdigit():
                    return False
                else:
                    return self.d(self) == self.d(other)
        __le__ = object.__le__
        __ne__ = object.__ne__
        __gt__ = object.__gt__
        __ge__ = object.__ge__
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.d(self) < self.d(other)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.d(self) == self.d(other)
    __le__ = object.__le__
    __ne__ = object.__ne__
    __gt__ = object.__gt__
    __ge__ = object.__ge__
```

```
import functools
import itertools


@functools.total_ordering
class NaturalStringB(str):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}({})".format\
            ( type(self).__name__
            , super().__repr__()
            )
    d = lambda s: "".join(c.lower()+c.swapcase() for c in s)
    d = staticmethod(d)
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(self, type(other)):
            return NotImplemented
        groups = map(lambda i: itertools.groupby(i, type(self).isdigit), (self, other))
        zipped = itertools.zip_longest(*groups)
        for s,o in zipped:
            if s is None:
                return True
            if o is None:
                return False
            s_k, s_v = s[0], "".join(s[1])
            o_k, o_v = o[0], "".join(o[1])
            if s_k and o_k:
                s_v, o_v = int(s_v), int(o_v)
                if s_v == o_v:
                    continue
                return s_v < o_v
            elif s_k:
                return True
            elif o_k:
                return False
            else:
                s_v, o_v = self.d(s_v), self.d(o_v)
                if s_v == o_v:
                    continue
                return s_v < o_v
        return False
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(self, type(other)):
            return NotImplemented
        groups = map(lambda i: itertools.groupby(i, type(self).isdigit), (self, other))
        zipped = itertools.zip_longest(*groups)
        for s,o in zipped:
            if s is None or o is None:
                return False
            s_k, s_v = s[0], "".join(s[1])
            o_k, o_v = o[0], "".join(o[1])
            if s_k and o_k:
                s_v, o_v = int(s_v), int(o_v)
                if s_v == o_v:
                    continue
                return False
            elif s_k or o_k:
                return False
            else:
                s_v, o_v = self.d(s_v), self.d(o_v)
                if s_v == o_v:
                    continue
                return False
        return True
    __le__ = object.__le__
    __ne__ = object.__ne__
    __gt__ = object.__gt__
    __ge__ = object.__ge__
```

```
import functools
import itertools
import enum


class OrderingType(enum.Enum):
    PerWordSwapCase         = lambda s: s.lower()+s.swapcase()
    PerCharacterSwapCase    = lambda s: "".join(c.lower()+c.swapcase() for c in s)


class NaturalOrdering:
    @classmethod
    def by(cls, ordering):
        def wrapper(string):
            return cls(string, ordering)
        return wrapper
    def __init__(self, string, ordering=OrderingType.PerCharacterSwapCase):
        self.string = string
        self.groups = [ (k,int("".join(v)))
                            if k else
                        (k,ordering("".join(v)))
                            for k,v in
                        itertools.groupby(string, str.isdigit)
                      ]
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}({})".format\
            ( type(self).__name__
            , self.string
            )
    def __lesser(self, other, default):
        if not isinstance(self, type(other)):
            return NotImplemented
        for s,o in itertools.zip_longest(self.groups, other.groups):
            if s is None:
                return True
            if o is None:
                return False
            s_k, s_v = s
            o_k, o_v = o
            if s_k and o_k:
                if s_v == o_v:
                    continue
                return s_v < o_v
            elif s_k:
                return True
            elif o_k:
                return False
            else:
                if s_v == o_v:
                    continue
                return s_v < o_v
        return default
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.__lesser(other, default=False)
    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.__lesser(other, default=True)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(self, type(other)):
            return NotImplemented
        for s,o in itertools.zip_longest(self.groups, other.groups):
            if s is None or o is None:
                return False
            s_k, s_v = s
            o_k, o_v = o
            if s_k and o_k:
                if s_v == o_v:
                    continue
                return False
            elif s_k or o_k:
                return False
            else:
                if s_v == o_v:
                    continue
                return False
        return True
    # functools.total_ordering doesn't create single-call wrappers if both
    # __le__ and __lt__ exist, so do it manually.
    def __gt__(self, other):
        op_result = self.__le__(other)
        if op_result is NotImplemented:
            return op_result
        return not op_result
    def __ge__(self, other):
        op_result = self.__lt__(other)
        if op_result is NotImplemented:
            return op_result
        return not op_result
    # __ne__ is the only implied ordering relationship, it automatically
    # delegates to __eq__
```

```
>>> import natsort
>>> import timeit
>>> l1 = ['Apple', 'corn', 'apPlE', 'arbour', 'Corn', 'Banana', 'apple', 'banana']
>>> l2 = list(map(str, range(30)))
>>> l3 = ["{} {}".format(x,y) for x in l1 for y in l2]
>>> print(timeit.timeit('sorted(l3+["0"], key=NaturalStringA)', number=10000, globals=globals()))
362.4729259099986
>>> print(timeit.timeit('sorted(l3+["0"], key=NaturalStringB)', number=10000, globals=globals()))
189.7340817489967
>>> print(timeit.timeit('sorted(l3+["0"], key=NaturalOrdering.by(OrderingType.PerCharacterSwapCase))', number=10000, globals=globals()))
69.34636392899847
>>> print(timeit.timeit('natsort.natsorted(l3+["0"], alg=natsort.ns.GROUPLETTERS | natsort.ns.LOWERCASEFIRST)', number=10000, globals=globals()))
98.2531585780016
```

Natural sorting is both pretty complicated and vaguely defined as a problem. Don't forget to run `unicodedata.normalize(...)` beforehand, and consider use `str.casefold()` rather than `str.lower()`. There are probably subtle encoding issues I haven't considered. So I tentatively recommend the [natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) library. I took a quick glance at the github repository; the code maintenance has been stellar.

All the algorithms I've seen depend on tricks such as duplicating and lowering characters, and swapping case. While this doubles the running time, an alternative would require a total natural ordering on the input character set. I don't think this is part of the unicode specification, and since there are many more unicode digits than `[0-9]`, creating such a sorting would be equally daunting. If you want locale-aware comparisons, prepare your strings with [`locale.strxfrm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.strxfrm) per Python's [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#odd-and-ends).

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm I use is `padzero_with_lower` as defined as:

```py
import re

def padzero_with_lower(s):
    return re.sub(r'\d+', lambda m: m.group(0).rjust(10, '0'), s).lower()
```

The algorithm finds:

- finds and pads numbers of any length, to a large enough length, e.g. 10
- then, it turns the string into lower case

Here's an example usage:

```
print(padzero_with_lower('file1.txt'))   # file0000000001.txt
print(padzero_with_lower('file12.txt'))  # file0000000012.txt
print(padzero_with_lower('file23.txt'))  # file0000000023.txt
print(padzero_with_lower('file123.txt')) # file0000000123.txt
print(padzero_with_lower('file301.txt')) # file0000000301.txt
print(padzero_with_lower('Dir2/file15.txt'))  # dir0000000002/file0000000015.txt
print(padzero_with_lower('dir2/file123.txt')) # dir0000000002/file0000000123.txt
print(padzero_with_lower('dir15/file2.txt'))  # dir0000000015/file0000000002.txt
print(padzero_with_lower('Dir15/file15.txt')) # dir0000000015/file0000000015.txt
print(padzero_with_lower('elm0'))  # elm0000000000
print(padzero_with_lower('elm1'))  # elm0000000001
print(padzero_with_lower('Elm2'))  # elm0000000002
print(padzero_with_lower('elm9'))  # elm0000000009
print(padzero_with_lower('elm10')) # elm0000000010
print(padzero_with_lower('Elm11')) # elm0000000011 
print(padzero_with_lower('Elm12')) # elm0000000012
print(padzero_with_lower('elm13')) # elm0000000013
```

With this function tested, we can now use it as our key, i.e.

```
lis = ['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13']
lis.sort(key=padzero_with_lower)
print(lis)
# Output: ['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13']
```

Answer (score 3):

A compact solution, based on the transformation of the string into a `List[Tuple(str, int)]`.

### Code

```py
def string_to_pairs(s, pairs=re.compile(r"(\D*)(\d*)").findall):
    return [(text.lower(), int(digits or 0)) for (text, digits) in pairs(s)[:-1]]
```

### Demonstration

```py
sorted(['Elm11', 'Elm12', 'Elm2', 'elm0', 'elm1', 'elm10', 'elm13', 'elm9'], key=string_to_pairs)
```

Output:

```py
['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13']
```

### Tests

#### Transformation

```py
assert string_to_pairs("") == []
assert string_to_pairs("123") == [("", 123)]
assert string_to_pairs("abc") == [("abc", 0)]
assert string_to_pairs("123abc") == [("", 123), ("abc", 0)]
assert string_to_pairs("abc123") == [("abc", 123)]
assert string_to_pairs("123abc456") == [("", 123), ("abc", 456)]
assert string_to_pairs("abc123efg") == [("abc", 123), ("efg", 0)]
```

#### Sorting

```py
# Some extracts from the test suite of the natsort library. Permalink:
# https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort/blob/e3c32f5638bf3a0e9a23633495269bea0e75d379/tests/test_natsorted.py

sort_data = [
    (  # same as test_natsorted_can_sort_as_unsigned_ints_which_is_default()
        ["a50", "a51.", "a50.31", "a-50", "a50.4", "a5.034e1", "a50.300"],
        ["a5.034e1", "a50", "a50.4", "a50.31", "a50.300", "a51.", "a-50"],
    ),
    (  # same as test_natsorted_numbers_in_ascending_order()
        ["a2", "a5", "a9", "a1", "a4", "a10", "a6"],
        ["a1", "a2", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a9", "a10"],
    ),
    (  # same as test_natsorted_can_sort_as_version_numbers()
        ["1.9.9a", "1.11", "1.9.9b", "1.11.4", "1.10.1"],
        ["1.9.9a", "1.9.9b", "1.10.1", "1.11", "1.11.4"],
    ),
    (  # different from test_natsorted_handles_filesystem_paths()
        [
            "/p/Folder (10)/file.tar.gz",
            "/p/Folder (1)/file (1).tar.gz",
            "/p/Folder/file.x1.9.tar.gz",
            "/p/Folder (1)/file.tar.gz",
            "/p/Folder/file.x1.10.tar.gz",
        ],
        [
            "/p/Folder (1)/file (1).tar.gz",
            "/p/Folder (1)/file.tar.gz",
            "/p/Folder (10)/file.tar.gz",
            "/p/Folder/file.x1.9.tar.gz",
            "/p/Folder/file.x1.10.tar.gz",
        ],
    ),
    (  # same as test_natsorted_path_extensions_heuristic()
        [
            "Try.Me.Bug - 09 - One.Two.Three.[text].mkv",
            "Try.Me.Bug - 07 - One.Two.5.[text].mkv",
            "Try.Me.Bug - 08 - One.Two.Three[text].mkv",
        ],
        [
            "Try.Me.Bug - 07 - One.Two.5.[text].mkv",
            "Try.Me.Bug - 08 - One.Two.Three[text].mkv",
            "Try.Me.Bug - 09 - One.Two.Three.[text].mkv",
        ],
    ),
    (  # same as ns.IGNORECASE for test_natsorted_supports_case_handling()
        ["Apple", "corn", "Corn", "Banana", "apple", "banana"],
        ["Apple", "apple", "Banana", "banana", "corn", "Corn"],
    ),

]

for (given, expected) in sort_data:
    assert sorted(given, key=string_to_pairs) == expected
```

### Bonus

If your strings mix non-ascii texts and numbers, you may be interested in composing `string_to_pairs()` with the function `remove_diacritics()` I give [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71408065/173003).

Answer (score 2):

This is a more advanced solution, improved from Claudiu and Mark Byers:

- It uses [`casefold()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40348174/14348748) instead of `lower()` to match strings
- You can pass another key lambda to select an inner element (as you are used to with a normal sort function)
- It works of course with `list.sort`, `sorted`, `max`, etc.

```py
def natural_sort(key=None, _nsre=re.compile('([0-9]+)')):
    return lambda x: [int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.casefold()
            for text in _nsre.split(key(x) if key else x)]
```

Example usage:

```
# Original solution
data.sort(key=natural_sort())

# Select an additional key
image_files.sort(key=natural_sort(lambda x: x.original_filename))
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are good for the **specific example** that was shown, but miss several useful cases for the more general question of natural sort. I just got bit by one of those cases, so created a more thorough solution:

```
def natural_sort_key(string_or_number):
    """
    by Scott S. Lawton <scott@ProductArchitect.com> 2014-12-11; public domain and/or CC0 license

    handles cases where simple 'int' approach fails, e.g.
        ['0.501', '0.55'] floating point with different number of significant digits
        [0.01, 0.1, 1]    already numeric so regex and other string functions won't work (and aren't required)
        ['elm1', 'Elm2']  ASCII vs. letters (not case sensitive)
    """

    def try_float(astring):
        try:
            return float(astring)
        except:
            return astring

    if isinstance(string_or_number, basestring):
        string_or_number = string_or_number.lower()

        if len(re.findall('[.]\d', string_or_number)) <= 1:
            # assume a floating point value, e.g. to correctly sort ['0.501', '0.55']
            # '.' for decimal is locale-specific, e.g. correct for the Anglosphere and Asia but not continental Europe
            return [try_float(s) for s in re.split(r'([\d.]+)', string_or_number)]
        else:
            # assume distinct fields, e.g. IP address, phone number with '.', etc.
            # caveat: might want to first split by whitespace
            # TBD: for unicode, replace isdigit with isdecimal
            return [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in re.split(r'(\d+)', string_or_number)]
    else:
        # consider: add code to recurse for lists/tuples and perhaps other iterables
        return string_or_number
```

Test code and several links (on and off of StackOverflow) are here:
http://productarchitect.com/code/better-natural-sort.py

Feedback welcome. That's not meant to be a definitive solution; just a step forward.

Comment: In your test script to which you link, `natsorted` and `humansorted` fail because they were used incorrectly... you tried to pass `natsorted` as a key but its actually the sorting function itself.  You should have tried `natsort_keygen()`.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Mark Byers answer, here is an adaptation which accepts the `key` parameter, and is more PEP8-compliant.

```py
def natsorted(seq, key=None):
    def convert(text):
        return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

    def alphanum(obj):
        if key is not None:
            return [convert(c) for c in re.split(r'([0-9]+)', key(obj))]
        return [convert(c) for c in re.split(r'([0-9]+)', obj)]

    return sorted(seq, key=alphanum)
```

I also made a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/edouardtheron/5e23e494f5cfbd94cf5e19201d63ccaa)

Comment: (-1) this answer doesn't bring anything new compared to Mark's (any linter can PEP8-ify some code). Or maybe the `key` parameter? But this is also exemplified in @beauburrier's answer

Answer (score 1):

```py
def sort_naturally(lst: list) -> list:
    max_str_len = max([len(s) for s in lst])
    return sorted(lst, key=lambda s: s.zfill(max_str_len + 1))
```

FYI the built-in function `str.zfill(width)` returns a copy of the string left filled with ASCII `0` digits to make a string of length *width*. See official documentation to learn more: [docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill)

Answer (score 0):

Let me submit my own take on this need:

```py
from typing import Tuple, Union, Optional, Generator


StrOrInt = Union[str, int]


# On Python 3.6, string concatenation is REALLY fast
# Tested myself, and this fella also tested:
# https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/string-concat.html
def griter(s: str) -> Generator[StrOrInt, None, None]:
    last_was_digit: Optional[bool] = None
    cluster: str = ""
    for c in s:
        if last_was_digit is None:
            last_was_digit = c.isdigit()
            cluster += c
            continue
        if c.isdigit() != last_was_digit:
            if last_was_digit:
                yield int(cluster)
            else:
                yield cluster
            last_was_digit = c.isdigit()
            cluster = ""
        cluster += c
    if last_was_digit:
        yield int(cluster)
    else:
        yield cluster
    return


def grouper(s: str) -> Tuple[StrOrInt, ...]:
    return tuple(griter(s))
```

Now if we have the list like such:

```py
filelist = [
    'File3', 'File007', 'File3a', 'File10', 'File11', 'File1', 'File4', 'File5',
    'File9', 'File8', 'File8b1', 'File8b2', 'File8b11', 'File6'
]
```

We can simply use the `key=` kwarg to do a natural sort:

```py
>>> sorted(filelist, key=grouper)
['File1', 'File3', 'File3a', 'File4', 'File5', 'File6', 'File007', 'File8', 
'File8b1', 'File8b2', 'File8b11', 'File9', 'File10', 'File11']
```

The drawback here is of course, as it is now, the function will sort uppercase letters before lowercase letters.

I'll leave the implementation of a case-insenstive grouper to the reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records, here is yet another variant of Mark Byers' simple solution, similar to the one suggested by Walter Tross, which avoids calling `isdigit()`. This not only makes it faster, but also avoids the problems that can occur because `isdigit()` considers more unicode chars as digits than the the regex `\d+`.

```py
import re
from itertools import cycle

_re_digits = re.compile(r"(\d+)")


def natural_comparison_key(key):
    return tuple(
        int(part) if is_digit else part
        for part, is_digit in zip(_re_digits.split(key), cycle((False, True)))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version of Mark Byers's answer. This version demonstrates how to pass in an attribute name, that is to be used to evaluate the objects in the list.

```
def natural_sort(l, attrib):
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key.__dict__[attrib])]
    return sorted(l, key=alphanum_key)

results = natural_sort(albums, 'albumid')
```

Where `albums` is a list of Album instances, and `albumid` is an string attribute that nominally has numbers in it.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you simply use the `key` keyword argument of `sorted` to achieve your desired list
For example:

```
to_order= [e2,E1,e5,E4,e3]
ordered= sorted(to_order, key= lambda x: x.lower())
    # ordered should be [E1,e2,e3,E4,e5]
```

Comment: this doesnt handle digits. `a_51` would be after`a500`, although 500>51

Comment: True, my answer simply matches the given example of Elm11 and elm1. Missed the request for natural sort specifically and the marked answer is probably the best one here :)

Answer (score -1):

```
a = ['H1', 'H100', 'H10', 'H3', 'H2', 'H6', 'H11', 'H50', 'H5', 'H99', 'H8']
b = ''
c = []

def bubble(bad_list):#bubble sort method
        length = len(bad_list) - 1
        sorted = False

        while not sorted:
                sorted = True
                for i in range(length):
                        if bad_list[i] > bad_list[i+1]:
                                sorted = False
                                bad_list[i], bad_list[i+1] = bad_list[i+1], bad_list[i] #sort the integer list 
                                a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i] #sort the main list based on the integer list index value

for a_string in a: #extract the number in the string character by character
        for letter in a_string:
                if letter.isdigit():
                        #print letter
                        b += letter
        c.append(b)
        b = ''

print 'Before sorting....'
print a
c = map(int, c) #converting string list into number list
print c
bubble(c)

print 'After sorting....'
print c
print a
```

**Acknowledgments**:

[Bubble Sort Homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895371/bubble-sort-homework)

[How to read a string one letter at a time in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633942/how-to-read-a-string-one-letter-at-a-time-in-python)

Answer (score -3):

```
>>> import re
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(re.findall(r'\d+$', x)[0]))
['elm0', 'elm1', 'Elm2', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13']
```

Comment: @SilentGhost: Can you explain the `re` part?

Comment: @AA: matches digits at the end of the string.

Comment: Your implementation only solves the numbers problem. The implementation fails if the strings don't have numbers in them. Try it on ['silent','ghost'] for instance (list index out of range).

Comment: @snaklie: your question fails to provide decent example case. You haven't explained what you're trying to do, and neither you have updated your question with this new information. You haven't posted anything you have tried, so please don't be so dismissive of my telepathy attempt.

Comment: @SilentGhost: First, I gave you an upvote because I think your answer is useful (even though it doesn't solve my problem). Second, I cannot cover all the possible cases with examples. I think I've given a pretty clear definition to natural sort. I don't think it's a good idea to give a complex example or a long definition to such a simple concept. You're welcome to edit my question if you can think of a better  formulation to the problem.

Comment: @snakile: but I don't know how to improve your question, because for me it's not clear at all how you'd want to deal with strings that do not have digits, but have different cases, lengths, etc.

Comment: @SilentGhost: I'd want to deal with such strings the same way Windows deals with such file names when it sorts files by name (ignore cases, etc). It seems clear to me, but anything I say seems clear to me, so I'm not to judge whether it's clear or not.

Comment: @snakile you have come nowhere near close defining natural search. That would be quite hard to do and would require a lot of detail. If you want the sort order used by windows explorer do you know that there is a simple api call that provides this?